# How to test ant design Select and Option properly using react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, select, antd, react-testing-library

Hi i read all next asks:
[ant design v4 breaks react testing library tests for Select and Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080116/ant-design-v4-breaks-react-testing-library-tests-for-select-and-autocomplete)

[How to change ant design select option using react testing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63635057/how-to-change-ant-design-select-option-using-react-testing-library)

[Ant Design and React Testing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197804/ant-design-and-react-testing-library)

[Ant Design & React Testing Library - Testing Form with Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574735/ant-design-react-testing-library-testing-form-with-select)
and others.

How can i test a ANTDesign Select component with react-testing-library, without jest ?

my component:

```
<Form.Item
    name="country"
    label="Country"
    rules={[
       {
           message: 'select a country',
           required: true,
       },
    ]}
>
    <Select options={[{ label: 'Spain', value: 'SP' }]} />
</Form.Item>
```

nothing has worked for me

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example